# Jira : Query inside linkedIssues

Tags: jira

We create jiras for tracking a release in a separate project. For eg: there is a project called Release and there will be jiras like Release-1, Release-2, Release-3. The actual code jiras for each release are linked to the release jira- something like Dev-1,Dev-2 linked to Release-1, Dev-3,Dev-4 linked to Release-2 etc. Each release jira has a type defined. I want to find all the dev jiras that are linked to the release jiras which has type say "XYZ". How can i achieve that? Tried out issue in linkedIssues() but its not working.

Comment: By "we create jiras for tracking" do you mean you create a Jira issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue related to this: [I cannot run issueFunction in JQL](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/I-cannot-run-issueFunction-in-JQL/qaq-p/3899)

If you mean "issues" by "jiras"

then please refer to the following example:

Jira Project Release

- Release-1 > linked to Dev-1, Dev-2
- Release-2 > linked to Dev-3, Dev-4

Jira Project Dev

- Dev-1 (bug)  > linked to Release-1
- Dev-2 (story)  > linked to Release-1
- Dev-3 (bug)  > linked to Release-2
- Dev-4 (story)  > linked to Release-2

Say I want to query all the bugs in Dev project related to Release-1. Please take note that you will need to have the Adaptavist Scriptrunner Jira plugin.

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOfAll("issue in (Release-1)") and type = Bug
```